# Site.com deployment to other organisaton using change set

Tags: change-set, community-cloud, experience-cloud, experience-bundle

I am facing this error while trying to deploy a community portal to another organization

> We couldn't validate componentAttributes in partnerportalv31/views/recordList.json for component 0ff249c1-7e01-45c1-a2e5-10fce9c43a9d. Error: attribute [scope]: Specify a valid entity.. Check your file and try again.

Comment: Have you checked with workaround posted over this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/333800/how-do-we-deploy-an-experience-bundle-to-a-scratch-org-properly)?

Comment: Hello what I did is I removed those components causing the problem, and I'll drag them again in the org destination, the workarounds did not work for me, I think it's a bug or something otherwise couldn't find any information in documentation!